# My JSON Server from Typicode updating database in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, api, json-server

I've been recently trying to work with a fake API using my json server from typicode. Using fake APIs is pretty new to me so my question might soung a little odd.

Am I understanding the concept of this fake API server right, that I can update the database with a post request in ReactJS? Or does the database never change through post request and I do only get a result in my console log?

In particular I am trying to post form data from a form to the my json server through a post request.

Thanks so far!

The code I use to post data:

```
axios.post(`my-url`, { user })
                    .then(res => {
                      console.log(res);
                      console.log(res.data);
                    })
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) package and using the server like that. In this case, the successful POST requests you make will be persisted in the file you provided to the server or the default one if you don't provide any specific file.

If you want to use `json-server` and make the changes persisted, you can use its npm package:

```
npm install -g json-server
```

Then, create a `db.json` file in your project directory and provide the data structure you want to use:

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ]
}
```

If you don't provide a `db.json` file it creates automatically when you start the server. So, it is up to you.

Then, you should start the server:

```
json-server db.json
```

The server will be on port `3000`, if there is another app running on this port, you can specify the port when starting it:

```
json-server db.json -p 3001
```

Now, you can make requests to `http://localhost:3001/posts`. Just check [its documentation](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) about the requests.

Comment: Yes thats right, I am using the json-server you mentioned. As I understand you right: my post request should be visible in my json file after a successful submission?

Comment: Indeed. This is the whole point of installing and using the server.

Comment: Okay, I installed it on here: https://my-json-server.typicode.com/aaronjoeldev/demo is there something wrong with the setup? Because my post requests do not change anything

Comment: This is something else they provide. I was talking about the local npm package. Have you done the instructions they explain [here](https://my-json-server.typicode.com/)? Like creating a repo on Github and create a `db.json` file there? By the way, don't add an answer if you want to make updates to your question. Just edit your question and make the updates there.

Comment: Well and this is what they say: "To be able to provide a free service to as many people as possible during this phase, the project comes with a few limits:

Changes are faked and aren't persisted (just like JSONPlaceholder)"... so changes are not persisted if you use this method.

Comment: Thank you so far for your support! 
I did follow the instructions from them. But as you mentioned: the changes are faked. I wasn't aware of that. So if I would set up a local json server and do a post request, the database file should be changed locally, right? If so: what is the best practice to do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. In this way, the changes will be persisted. Honestly, I suppose there isn't any best practice about faking the API like that. This is just for learning purposes, so set the server, fake the API, try and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a post request to this server [https://my-json-server.typicode.com/${github-username}/${github-repo}/${event}](https://my-json-server.typicode.com/$%7Bgithub-username%7D/$%7Bgithub-repo%7D/$%7Bevent%7D),

As of the time of this response, you can only make a get request, I advise you to use JSON-server on your local machine.

Create a db.json file on the project folder,

Example add something like this to the file

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "category": "animal welfare",
      "date": "January 28, 2022",
      "time": "12:00",
    },
    {
      "id": 456,
      "category": "nature",
      "date": "January 30, 2022",
      "time": "11:00",
    },
}
```

run npm install -g json-server
and json-server --watch db.json to provide the baseUrl that will be needed to make your requests